# How to use Cross Platform Location Services in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, geolocation, location, cross-platform

I am building a Xamarin.Forms (PCL) app, with some BLE data collection and Azure Mobile Services to push data entries to the cloud. I would like to add location services data to that, so I know where the BLE data was received. Is there a platform agnostic way of doing this with Xamarin? So far, I don't have any references to specific platforms and for the sake to simplicity, share-ability and read-ability, I would love to keep that the same.

Any suggestions on how this could be achieved would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a platform independent interface for geo location and a corresponding implementation for each platform.
Yes there are some ways of doing it.

I prefer the [MVVMCross Location Plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AomjbED9AzM). You find the sources of the example in the video on [GitHub](https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-08-Location).

An alternative way is using the [XLabs Geolocator](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Geolocator) for Xamarin.Forms.